# iOS: resize screen when keyboard appears (in HTML5 APP)

Tags: ios, css, html, cordova

I have a Phonegap 4.0 app in iOS with an `<input />`.

When I focus the `<input />`, the entire screen moves up, and does NOT resize. But I want the **size** of the screen to **adjust** to the new, smaller screen with keyboard.

Goal is to keep the header visible:

```
<header style="position:absolute; top:0: left:0; right:0; height: 30px;">
  ...
</header>
```

My current index.html `viewport` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

This has no effect:

```
<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false" />
```

Neither does adding `height=device-height` to viewport tag..

Comment: Hi, did you find any answer?

Answer (score 0):

Change 'minimum-scale=1.0' to 'maximum-scale=1.0'.  By using minimum-scale you are saying that the contents cannot resize any smaller, like when the keyboard comes up in your case.